# Does sitting whilst peeing reduce prostate issues?

Tags: medical-science, healthcare

There are a number of articles that combine the statement that men should sit while peeing for hygiene reasons* and that sitting whilst peeing reduces prostate issues.

The problem is that I cannot seem to find the original or a reference to any actual research behind the claim. I would like to know if this study really exists and then is it enough to really base behavior on.

> Medical research reported in Sweden’s Folket newspaper said that
>   sitting might mean reduced prostate cancer risk and be better for you
>   in the bedroom. That’s because the bladder empties more efficiently
>   when men take a seat while urinating, and this improved bladder
>   release supposedly decreases prostate problems and allows for a longer
>   and healthier sex life.

One example website http://www.mensfitness.com/blogs/could-peeing-sitting-down-help-your-sex-life
*This is left in the question for context reasons

Comment: I've also heard the opposite claim that sitting reduces the efficiency of bladder emptying and thus leads to increased chance of prostate cancer.

Comment: This is exactly why i'm after a reliabel answer, Can you direct me to some of the claims, i might update the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Research shows that the sitting voiding position is preferred to the standing  position for patients with problems of the lower urinary tract causing benign prostate hyperplasia and there is no medically superior posture for urination in healthy men.

> In this report we've looked at the influences of changing urination posture on the maximum urine flow, the time spent voiding and the amount of urine that is left in the bladder. We conclude that the sitting posture is the best position for men with urination problems, e.g. due to an enlarged prostate to urinate in, whereas no difference was found in healthy men. This is clinically important, because residual urine may result in complications such as cystitis and bladder stones. [Source: Urinating Standing versus Sitting: Position Is of Influence in Men with Prostate Enlargement. A Systematic Review and Meta-Analysis](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4106761/)